# value for message cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to string Error

Tags: javascript, php, react-native

I always get an error when trying to run an app in Visual Studio Code using this code, but this code worked on my brother's PC. It worked well until the JSON part came. The error is:

> value for message cannot be cast from ReadableNativeMap to string

**React code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {Alert, Button, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text,} from "react-native";

function App(){

  const[t1,setT1] = useState("Name");
  const[t2,setT2] = useState("Gender");
  const[t3,setT3] = useState("Mobile");
  const[t4,setT4] = useState("X");
  const[t5,setT5] = useState("Y");

  const ui=(
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.main}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{t1}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{t2}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{t3}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{t4}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{t5}</Text>
      <Button title="Send Request" onPress={f1}/>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );

  function f1(){

    var obj2= {"x":50,"y":100,};
    var json2= JSON.stringify(obj2);

    var requestObject={
      method:"GET",
    }

    var request = fetch("http://10.0.2.2/react_php?json="+json2,requestObject);
    request.then(response => response.json()).then(json=>{
        setT1(json.name);
        setT2(json.gender);
        setT3(json.mobile);
        setT4(json.x);
        setT5(json.y);
    }).catch(error=>{
        Alert.alert("Error",error);
    });
  };

  return ui;
}
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php

$json2 = $_GET("json");
$obj2 = json_decode($json2);

$obj1 = new stdClass();
$obj1->name = "shavi";
$obj1->gender = "female";
$obj1->mobile = "0713456789";
$obj1->x = $obj2->x;
$obj1->y = $obj2->y;

$json1 = json_encode($obj1);
echo $json1;

?>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: That's Visual Studio Code, not Android Studio! I edited the question for you. You'll probably do a lot better at programming if you at least know the names of the basic tools you're using - it does say it right there in the title bar of the app! Then you might find it's easier to search online about your problems, for one thing. Success in programming requires a lot of attention to detail...knowing which application you're using to write the code is really the first, most basic detail you could pay attention to... :-)

Answer (score 0):

can you try encode url after stringnifing the json. i hope this helps!

```
var request = fetch("http://10.0.2.2/react_php?json="+encodeURIComponent(json2),requestObject);
request.then(response => response.json()).then(json=>{
    setT1(json.name);
    setT2(json.gender);
    setT3(json.mobile);
    setT4(json.x);
    setT5(json.y);
}).catch(error=>{
    Alert.alert("Error",error);
});
```

};